# Objective C Tap Gesture no working after frame resize

Tags: objective-c, resize, frame, tap

I making an ipad application with screen split in half. Each side contains a container and each container holds UIView.

In the left uiView i have a uiScrollView with multiple elements (customs uiview) inside, like a grid but with scroll, and each element support tap gesture.
   When i tap each element they work fine and behave like they are suppose to. lets say they do a NSLog(@"tapped!").

Problem comes when i resize either the entire view that holds the scroll view or the Container like so:

```
navigationVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 338,768);
```

The tap stops working! But if i resize back to its original frame, tap starts working again.

```
navigationVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, originalWidth ,768);
```

I thought the problem would be the elements re-arrange when i resize the scroll view, but in fact its not.

   The frame is being resized when i swipe the entire application either left or right.

EDIT:

Behaviour diagram: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmax6.png

EDIT2: didnt figure it out yet, but i see now that element bound's are changing when the frame is resized.

Comment: kindly check the `contentSize` of the scroll view when you change the frame and also set the property `clipsToBounds = YES` of the scrollView. Now rotate the device and see if you still could see the UIViews

Comment: hey, clipsToBounds = YES is set. 
The scroll content size as im swapping left and right are:
<------ (width=333, height=14233)
-------> (width=663, height=7193)

Rotating the device and mantaining it with width = 663 the tap works fine.

Comment: no it is not. the problem remains when the frame is changed in size not in position.

Comment: Ok, so i did some more testing, and i now only change the frame width from 660 to 600 instead of 330.. what happens is that the tap works, but only in abit more then half element. (elements have 150 px) so i assume only 90px are accepting the tap.. this is so wierd.. maybe everytime i change the frame i have to remove and add the gesture again?

Comment: Can you add screenshots of the UI?

Comment: unfortunantly because its for a client i will not put the ui as is.. but i make a diagram how it works and what i have now:
http://i.imgur.com/4vKpHLQ.png?1

Comment: Ive also tried to remove and add the tapGesture after remake the frame.. and the result is the same.

Comment: Well, what I can figure out is that it could be the issue with the `contentSize` of the `scrollView`. How you want your `scrollView` to **scroll**? I mean **horizontally** or **vertically**? You need to get the right most and bottom most UIView and set the `contentSize` accordingly. You can use `CGRectGetMaxX(RightmostUIView.frame)` & `CGRectGetMaxY(BottommostUIView.frame)`

Comment: So whenever you update `frame` try updating the `contentSize` as well and then lets see if it works

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

Problem was that when i resized the scrollView the elements.Bounds where changing too. Then i went digging why... could only be something like a anchor... i then started to change a few properties on my XIB.

Under "Simulated Metrics", changed the "Size" drop-down from "Freeform" (add 150, 45) to "Inferred".

Forced the size on initWithCoder, compiled, and it worked.

Thanks Burhanuddin Sunelwala for trying to debug this with me.